# rsyslog suspending while creating directories and files

Tags: 18.04, server, services, log, rsyslog

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver) for details click [here](https://pastebin.com/jdDnW1V9).

rsyslog version used `rsyslogd  8.2001.0.aeabf0e9703b` for details click [here](https://pastebin.com/H0Z8qrUT).

`/etc/rsyslog.conf` file click [here](https://pastebin.com/ZNEyVwwL).

I copied the default `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` file overwriting earlier file which I modified from the backup, (as suggested by few users here in comments) to ensure default configuration is not tamppered with, click [here](https://pastebin.com/r2gYGmAQ) who want to check the default file is intact.

Then created a new file `/etc/rsyslog.d/central-log-server.conf` where I updated my configuration, which is as it was earlier:

```
root@opennms-otrs:~# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
template(name="RemoteLogs" type="string" string="/var/log/remote-servers/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.%Month%-%Date%-%Year%.log" type="list") {
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="year")
    constant(value="-")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="month")
    constant(value="-")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="day")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="hour")
    constant(value=":")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="minute")
    constant(value=":")
    property(name="timereported" dateFormat="second")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="app-name")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="severity")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" ) # add space if $msg doesn't start with one
    property(name="msg" droplastlf="on" )  # add trailing blank line after each $msg if there is none
    constant(value="\n")
}
*.* ?RemoteLogs
root@opennms-otrs:~#
```

The error log after restarting the rsyslog service is below

```
root@opennms-otrs:~# journalctl -f -u rsyslog
-- Logs begin at Sat 2019-12-14 12:17:22 IST. --
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan 04 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd[13431]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Sat Jan  4 19:10:30 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]

^C
root@opennms-otrs:~# tail -50 /var/log/remote-servers/opennms-otrs/rsyslogd.04-01-2020.log
Jan  4 19:00:01 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:00:01 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:00:01 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Sat Jan  4 19:00:31 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3" x-pid="13341" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 106
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 102
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3" x-pid="13431" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: file '/var/log/rsyslog.log': open error: Permission denied [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2433 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:01:23 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Sat Jan  4 19:01:53 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' resumed (module 'builtin:omfile') [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2359 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Jan  4 19:10:00 opennms-otrs rsyslogd: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), next retry is Sat Jan  4 19:10:30 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for suspension. [v8.2001.0.586a2bca05c3 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
root@opennms-otrs:~#
```

**What we want to achieve:**

1. Specific format within all log files, which can be imported as csv file later for more analysis:

   Month - day - Year - hour - minute - Seconds - Hostname - Application/Service - severity - message (add space if $msg doesn't start with one) - \n (Add blank line after each message)
2. All log files should be stored in their specifc hostname folders:

   ```
   /var/log/remote-servers/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.%Month%-%Date%-%Year%.log
   ```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure you should "format and fit all of this". This is simply a "dump all the information I can think of" and hope for free consulting. No thank you. Read all of that stuff yourself, try to understand EACH line, and only post the minimum to describe your problem.

Comment: @heynnema: Please help now I understand your consern & I tried to format everything to the best of my abilities. I hope you can review it and help me with it now. :)

Comment: @waltinator: Please help now I understand your consern & I tried to format everything to the best of my abilities. I hope you can review it and help me with it now. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add the various file info... however, you're **re-writing the entire /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf file**, destroying its original intent, and asking us to debug it for you. Probably won't happen. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema: I've restored the default 50-default.conf file as I had it backed up as 50-default.conf.orig before I started modifing it. Hence I hope that will ease things a bit. thanks for that advice though. I would appreciate if you can help me now to solve this issue.

Comment: Just to confirm that rsyslog is really working on its own, I'd remove `/etc/rsyslog.d/central-log-server.conf`, restart rsyslog, and confirm that it's working normally. Then, I'd recommend installing `glogg`. If logfile review/analysis is what you want, this tool might just work out of the box for you. Otherwise, you'll have to wait until one of the programmer-types here look at your code.

Comment: @heynnema: Yes that's correct. After restoring the default /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, I did restart the rsyslog service to ensure its working as expected without any warnings or errors. only after that I created a new file /etc/rsyslog.d/central-log-server.conf and then restarted the service and got errors this time, so definately there is something wronge with the conf I'm introducing :(

Comment: I'm not sure if this format is still working. The [configuration page for the omfilemodule](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omfile.html) fot rsyslogd v8.x lists things like `Template` as **obsolete legacy**

Comment: @RobertRiedl: I actuatly refered the same link to create my cutom configuration that I'm using above but not able to find out where I'm going wronge with it. I hope someone can help me find out the error here :)

Comment: @Hrish so, it works on another host ? With rsyslogd v8.x or higher ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl: thanks for your time to go throught the question. and No man it's not working anywhere I tried it on a test VM still the same result. there must be something wrong with the conf I created but not able to identify what is it.

Comment: Hm, have you tried reducing the config to the bare minimum and then adding line after line, to see which one is the offending one ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl after lot of tried I have figured out that the directory structure defination and log file format works saparately fine and as expected but does not work in congunction ... the the glich is there but not sure how to connect those then! :(